# How can I sync notes in iPhone with macbook pro and vice versa by using either bluetooth or using USB cable?

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, notes.app

I have iPhone 4 and macbook pro. I have some notes in my iPhone. I would like to sync those notes to my iPhone.  How can I sync notes in iPhone with macbook pro and vice versa by using either bluetooth or using USB cable which is used to charge iPhone and with out using any external account like iCloud or gmail?

**Research that I have done:**
I have Googled with the phrase "how to sync iphone notes with mac" and I got below result.
 along with other results.

[iOS: Syncing Notes](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4191)

How ever all those articles discuss the method with iCloud account. But I don't have iCloud account.

The below article seems to be very close to my question. How ever it didn't provide any solution to my problem.

[Notes was removed in Mountain Lion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4156737?start=0&tstart=0)

I have searched in apple.SE site also. How ever I found some results. But all of them are suggesting with some of the other email account.

How ever I would like to sync the notes with out Internet by using either USB cable which I used to charge iPhone or bluetooth.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following third party software:

iExplorer - http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/31722/iexplorer
iMazing - http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/27830/imazing
PhoneView - http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/25347/phoneview

I believe you will have to copy/paste the information manually.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like local syncing of Notes was [removed in Mountain Lion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4156737?start=0&tstart=0). You'll have to either roll back to Lion or find a third-party app that allows this.

Comment: My apologies for not specifying about this earlier. I had browsed through this article. How ever it is also not providing solution to my problem. But Since my reputation doesn't allow to add more than 2 hyperlinks, I couldn't talk about this in my question. Now I have replaced older one with this hyperlink. Thanks for bringing the point.

Answer (score -3):

I believe you can do it with iTunes. If not try iTools or iFunbox, both softwares have powerful tools.